# cca create: How to get rid of this Hallo World sample app

Tags: cordova-chrome-app

I'm just trying out cca and wondering how to get rid of this Hallo World sample app.

cca create always creates this Hallo World app and cca help does not reveal some params to create an app just like with cordova create:

```
$ cordova create test com.example.test MyApp
```

How would I do that with cca create?

Answer (score 0):

The create syntax is correct. Look int your config.xml and replace the is and the name.
Delete platform (platforms/android) and rebuild phonegap (phonegap build android).

This should do the trick.